# Which structure need for task?

Tags: java, spring

i want to create some structure, like this:

```
company {
  id: 1,
  name:'first',
  departments: [
                 {
                   department { id:1 }
                 },
                 {
                  department { id: 2 }
                  }
                 }
              ]
       }, 
       {
        id: 2,
        name:'second',
        departments: [
                       {
                         department { id: 1 }
                       },
                       {
                         department { id: 2 }
                       }
                     ]
      }
```

Looks like tree.

Please help, which tools(collections,maps) or something else i need to use for realise this task. Thank you.
And sorry for easy question.

And how create query for two this entities? 
for company i did: 
`List company = companyRepository.findAll();` 
and for department:

```
List departmentsByCompany_id = new LinkedList();

     Iterator<Company> iter = company.iterator();
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                departmentsbycompany_id.add(iter.next().getDepartments());
            }
```

but its doen`t work.

How added two entities in one collection)))

Comment: You need class `Department` with field `id` and class `Company` with fields `id` and collection of `Department`s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
class Company {
    int id;
    String name;
    Set<Department> departments;

    // getters, setters, logic, etc.
}

class Department {
    int id;

    // getters, setters, logic, etc.
}
```

Then your overall structure looks like a collection of `Company` objects (albeit a little malformed in your example):

```
Set<Company>
```

It's not really a [tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28data_structure%29), it's just a collection of objects each of which contains a collection of another kind of object.  A tree would be more recursive where each object refers to a parent or set of child objects of the same type.

Comment: don't forget to override **equals(Object o)** and **hashcode()** methods :)

Comment: @nafas: Good catch.  For a `Set<>` that would be pretty useful :)  (I guess any sort of collection would work in a pinch, I was assuming a need for uniqueness within the collection.)

Comment: @MattBearson: Code in comments is very difficult to read.  Perhaps you can explain the problem further in your question?  Note that if you're compounding an entirely new question onto the original then it may be worth asking a new Stack Overflow question.  Drastic changes to the original question invalidates existing answers and makes the thread confusing.

Comment: I redact my post, it`s easy, sorry for code in comments

Comment: @MattBearson: That sounds like it may be worth its own question.  It's not really clear what you mean by "it's not working", can you elaborate?  Do you get an error?  Unexpected results?  Please describe the problem, we can't debug your code for you.

Comment: ok, will be easy, if i ask it in another question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can create two classes, Company and Department as :
class Company {int id; String name; Department department}
Then you can use collection to store company object containing department details.

Answer (score 1):

A Company objet with 3 fields :

```
long id

String name

Set<Department> departments
```

And a Department objet with one field :

```
long id
```

Answer (score 0):

That pretty much looks like a JSON object.

If you want straight-up Java structures, which you can also manipulate, your structure seems pretty straight forward from your structure example:

You want a List of `Company` class.

Each `Company` class should have three field: `id`, `name` and list of `Department` class.

Each `Department` class should have a single field - `id`.